# Bootstrap 5 Grid with fixed and dynamic width force in same row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to build a grid system for my Blazor app with really small fixed size columns and a big one.
Dividing into the 12 grid columns using col-xs-* is not an option.
So far setting a custom width without the col class works, but with a long word (even with break-word overflow-wrap) my last column gets the full width in a new row.
I would like to render everything in one row like the second row in my sample below.

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row border">
        <div class="border" style="width:30px">X</div>
        <div class="border" style="width:40px">XX</div>
        <div class="col border" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">tooLongForThisRooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooow</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row border">
        <div class="border" style="width:30px">Y</div>
        <div class="border" style="width:40px">YY</div>
        <div class="col border" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text wrapping can be achieved with `.text-wrap` and `.text-break`.
Only columns should be descendants of rows. You either need to use `.col-1`, `.col-1`, `.col-10` inside side the `.row`, or put all three elements inside a 12 column flexbox container `.col-12.d-flex`:

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- flexbox -->
  <div class="row p-0">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex border p-0">
      <div class="p-2 border" style="width:30px !important;">X</div>
      <div class="p-2 border" style="width:40px !important;">XX</div>
      <div class="p-2 border text-wrap text-break">
        tooLongForThisRooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooow
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- grid -->
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="col-1 border" style="width:30px !important;">X</div>
    <div class="col-1 border" style="width:40px !important;">XX</div>
    <div class="col-10 border text-wrap text-break">
      tooLongForThisRooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooow
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border">
    <div class="border" style="width:30px">Y</div>
    <div class="border" style="width:40px">YY</div>
    <div class="col border" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long not too long</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is ignoring `width:# !important` when shrinking the width and adjusting it to the content. The grid version keeps the width no matter what. Now that I can set `col-1` with `width:# !important` the last text column stays in the same row. The last col should be `col` instead of `col-10` to fill the 100% width. Thanks for your help!